# IBM-Bluemix: image reported by IBM Containers compressed - smaller than local Docker engine

Tags: docker, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I am creating an **ibm-mobilefirst-starter container** but getting the below message.

```
Urgent message:

The size of an image reported by IBM Containers is now the compressed size of the image in the IBM Containers registry. This is smaller than the size of the same image in your local Docker engine.
```

and the container status keep showing **Your container is building** for a long time.

If I delete and re-create container, the same thing happens.

[image]

Comment: Please open up a defect for your service instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The urgent message that is shown indicates that the size of the image you see in the Bluemix UI is the compressed size and will be smaller than the size of the image on your local docker engine. It is a generic information message from IBM Containers and not an error or warning. I understand that the Warning sign is misleading. More information is available here : 
https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_images_building.html (Please refer to the note stated Important towards the end of the page)

Regarding the issue in creating the Container using the ibm-mobilefirst-starter, I was able to create an instance today (9th July 12 PM IST). I suggest you to try to create a new container instance. Also ensure that the container memory needed to build the container is available in your org.

Comment: Thanks, I was later able to create a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

@aahad This is a standard message that you get now a days when using containers and is not specific to the ibm-mobilefirst-starter image. Secondly - there were some recent outages in the container infrastructure - and you may have hit one of the issues. Make sure you have at least 1 GB of container memory in your account and try to create the ibm-mobilefirst-starter container again. Make sure you select the container size as 1 GB.

Alternately there is a new service that is launched called "Mobile Foundation" - you can try the developer plan.